# Silverlight new TouchPoint() causes a program crash

Tags: c#, silverlight, touch

I want to simulate `TouchPoint`s in Silverlight. The following code already raises an unhandled Exception:

```
currentTouchPoints[i] = new TouchPoint();
currentTouchPoints[i].SetValue(TouchPoint.PositionProperty, 
   new Point(x[i]+100+i*100,y[i]+500));
```

The first call to `new TouchPoint()` makes the program crash.

Comment: Which line *exactly* is causing the crash? I find it hard to believe that a call to `new TouchPoint()` is responsible. Unless `i` is out of range for the `currentTouchPoints` array.

Comment: What do you mean by crash? What exception is being thrown?

Comment: The line new TouchPoint is causing the crash. When I debug it calls Application_UnhandledException and nothing happens.

Comment: The debugger tells me the following: A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.dll

Answer (score 1):

i guess you are allowed to call the new TouchPoint(), but its TouchDevice would be not valid and all its properties are readonly, so it would be useless.

I haven't found a solution myself.

I'd create a custom class and use that one instead.

For example if you are using already the normal TouchPoint in your code and don't want to change everything, import this custom namespace instead of System.Windows.Input

```
namespace MyTouchPoint 
{

class TouchPoint
{
public Point Position = new Point (0,0);
public TouchDevice TouchDevice = new TouchDevice();

TouchPoint (int id_, Point position_) 
{
    TouchDevice.Id = id_;
    Position = position_;
}
};

class TouchDevice
{
public int Id = 0;
};

} // end namespace
```

cheers,
Lorenzo

Comment: ops, this is valid in WPF... not in Silverlight

Comment: yep it should, 

since I'm able to create a touchpoint even in silverlight using 'new TouchPoint()'

but this one is empty (TouchDevice is null, and position is 0,0) and besides all the properties are readonly, so there is no way to fill it.